# How to Binding composition based Observable Collection?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid

Say my model looks like something shown below,

```
public class Organization
    private string _organizationName;
    private List<Employee> _employees;
    private List<Contractor> _contractors;

    public string OrganizationName
    {
        get
        {
            return _organizationName;
        }
        set
        {
            _organizationName= value;
        }
    }

    public List<Employee> Employees
    {
        get { return _employees; }
        set { _employees = value; }


    }

    public List<Contractor> Contractors
    {
        get
        {
            return _contractors;
        }
        set
        {
            _contractors = value;
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

public int EmpID { get; set; }

    public double Salary { get; set; }

}
public class Contractor
{
public string Name { get; set; }

    public int ContractorID { get; set; }

    public double ExperianceCredit { get; set; }

}
```

I have one View(MainWindow) and one Associated ViewModel(OrganizationViewModel)

View(MainWindow)

Has three controls:

1)    ListView     -OrganizationListView
2)    DataGrid     -EmployeesDataGrid
3)    DataGrid     -ContractorsDataGrid

ViewModel(OrganizationViewModel)

```
private ObservableCollection<Organization> _organizations

    public ObservableCollection<Organization> Organizations
    {
        get
        {`enter code here`
            return _organizations;
        }
        set
        {
            _organizations = value;
        }
    }
```

Binding:

ListView  - OrganizationListView - Binds to Organizations(ObservableCollection)
DataGrid  - EmployeesDataGrid  -  Binds to Organizations.Employees
DataGrid  - ContractorsDataGrid -  Binds to Organizations.Contractors

I have a problem with accessing Employees
 & Contractors from Organizations(ObservableCollection) while trying to Bind it to the respective control in the view?

EmployeesDataGrid & ContractorsDataGrid should be dependent on OrganizationListView

Is this achievable or should i follow a different approach?

Comment: Can you post your XAML code (the binding code)?

Comment: What kind of problem do you have? The GUI does not show anything or what? Did you checked the Output if there is no BindingExpression? If the binding is ok and VM contains any data, all you have to do is to define the ItemTemplate for your ListViews

Comment: try to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for the Employees and Contractors properties in Model.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do, if I understand you properly is to have a list of organizations, that when you click on one of the organizations a table of employees and contractors for that organization are shown in the data grids.  Am I right?

If so, you are doing this the hard way.  What you want is to create a relation between the organization table and the contractor table and a separate relation between the organization table the employee table.  Doing this with POCO is really a fool's errand in my view.

The are many ways to do this, but my first choice would be a typed DataSet.  Setup 3 tables and 2 relations, create a view model containing the instantiated dataset.  Bind the organization table to the list view and the two relations to the datagrids and you are done!